# Python -> Cython -> C -> DLL -> Work on Cpp but not found module

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, dll, cython

I have a C file, it call Python function with Cython.

Python file have import torch(Pytorch 0.4.0), and function use torch.

Then I create the .dll with this C file.

The problem happen here:

When I use this dll in cpp file, it have ModuleNotFoundError.

Here is my simple code:

```
Environment:
  Windows 10 x64
  Visual Studio 2017
  Anaconda3
  Python 3.6
  Pytorch 0.4.0
  Cython 0.28.2
```

PyTest.pyx

```
import torch
cdef public void HelloWorld():
    print('Hello!')
    print(torch.__version__)
    print('World!')
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(name = 'PyTest',
      cmdclass = {'build_ext' : build_ext},
      ext_modules = cythonize('PyTest.pyx')
      )
```

run setup.py in terminal

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Generate files : PyTest.c and PyTest.h

Create C files : C_Test.c and C_Test.h

C_Test.h

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "PyTest.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
__declspec(dllexport) int testdll();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

C_Test.c

```
#include "C_Test.h"
int testdll()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    if(Py_IsInitialized())
        printf("Py_Initialize Done!\n");
    if(!PyInit_PyTest())
        printf("PyInit_PyTest Fail!\n");
    HelloWorld();
    Py_Finalize();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Developer command prompt for 2017:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC"
vcvarsall amd64
cd "{my C files path}"
cl /LD C_Test.c PyTest.c -I C:\Anaconda3\envs\Pytorch\include C:\Anaconda3\envs\Pytorch\libs\python36.lib
```

Generate C_Test.dll, C_Test.lib, C_Test.exp, C_Test.obj

Then create c++ project with Visual Studio 2017, and do something to make sure it can read C_Test.dll

CppTest.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Python.h"
#include "C_Test.h"
int main()
{
    testdll();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the result of my program execution:

```
Py_Initialize Done!
PyInit_PyTest Fail!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyTest.pyx", line 2, in init PyTest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <built-in method write of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x000002C2091877E0> returned a result with an error set
Exception ignored in: 'PyTest.HelloWorld'
SystemError: <built-in method write of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x000002C2091877E0> returned a result with an error set
Hello!
```